# how to disable pinch to zoom on an external JellyComb usb trackpad? windows 10 (not the built-in trackpad)

Tags: usb, touchpad

It seems that for windows, the generic driver for external interfaces is always a mouse, but weirdly it accepts and processes multi-touch gestures without the possibility to disable them. Can anyone help me do it? is it posible to enable disable pinch to zoom on an external touchpad? please, don’t take me to the default windows setting to disable pinch to zoom, it only works for the buil-in trackpad.

Comment: According to an answer on Amazon, https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx1RH8EBL04SNI9/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza, open Device Manager and select Touchpad to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Again, DrMoishe Pippik, the touchpad settings on windows apply only to the built-in touchpad. The usb touchpad is governed by mouse settings and does not have any multi-touch gestures to configure (yet it receives them from the usb touchpad)